# How to call textFieldShouldReturn from a number pad Xcode 9 Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set local notifications in my app. So far it works, though it works only with the default keypad. The values that the user enters for notifications should only be numbers. The problem is that the number pad does not contain a done button which the user needs to press to send the notifications; I am using the textFieldShouldReturn function. I have a done button that I added programmatically, but my questions are:

- How can I call the textFieldShouldReturn func inside the button I have created in the numberPad?
- If not able to do so, do I need to change my notifications completely?

I have seven switches and textfields, but I will only show one for demonstration purposes:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    let SCV = SettingsViewController()

    @IBOutlet weak var field1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var switch1: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var cell1: UIView!

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        field1 = self
        field1 = "0"
        field1 = UIColor.white

        if let ebrSwitchState = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "ebrState") as? Bool{
            if switch1state == true{
                switch1(true, animated: true)
                if let text1 = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "ebrValue") as? String{
                    field1 = true;
                    field1 = ebrText
                }
            }
            else{
                switch1.setOn(false, animated: false)
                field1.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func ebrValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if ebrSwitch.isOn{
            field1.isEnabled = true
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "state1")
        }
        else{
            field1.isEnabled = false
            field1.text = "0"
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "state1")
            center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["1"])
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        if (textField.tag == 0){
            UserDefaults.standard.set(ebrField.text, forKey: "1Value")
            LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPush(in: 1800, plant: 0)}
        else if(textField.tag == 1){
            UserDefaults.standard.set(etrField.text, forKey: "2Value")
            LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPush(in: 1800, plant: 1)
        }
        else if(textField.tag == 2){
            UserDefaults.standard.set(fscField.text, forKey: "fscValue")
            LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPush(in: 1800, plant: 2)
        }
        else if(textField.tag == 3){
            UserDefaults.standard.set(jdpField.text, forKey: "jdpValue")
            LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPush(in: 1800, plant: 3)
        }
        else if(textField.tag == 4){
            UserDefaults.standard.set(phrField.text, forKey: "phrValue")
            LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPush(in: 1800, plant: 4)
        }
        else if(textField.tag == 5){
            UserDefaults.standard.set(tcrField.text, forKey: "tcrValue")
            LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPush(in: 1800, plant: 5)
        }
        else if(textField.tag == 7){
            UserDefaults.standard.set(mlsField.text, forKey: "mlsValue")
            LocalPushManager.shared.sendLocalPush(in: 1800, plant: 6)
        }
        else{print("text field area went wrong")}

        return true;
    }

    // Hide keyboard when user touches outside keyboard
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be call when your keyboard type is **NumberPad**

Try use this instead, it can save your code :)

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("Can't be reach")
    return true
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == yourNumberPadTextFiled {
        print("\(String(describing: textField.text))")
        /// listen the string change and do whether you want
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: @matt ok , i changed it